# Right structure to place files in a web-project

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, web

I am extremely extremely new to learning web-development. I am using head-first java and while following its first chapter, I am completely stuck at one problem. So, straight to the problem:
I am using Apache-tomcat-7.0.55. In the webapps folder I have created my project, and the folder structure it has is as follows:

```
    /path_to/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps
                   --  /ch1/`my project folder`
                        --WEB-INF/ --web.xml     
                            --classes/ --Ch1servlet.class
```

and my web.xml is as follows :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
          version="2.4" 
 >
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Chapter1 Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Ch1servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Chapter1 Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Serv1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and the Ch1servlet.java file is as follows:

```
     public class Ch1servlet extends HttpServlet{
     public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  
     IOException{
             PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
             java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
              out.println("<html>" + 
                              "<body>" +
                                 "<h1 align=center>HF\'s Chapter1 Servlet</h1>" +
                                     "<br>" + today +   "</body>" + "</html>");
               }
       }
```

When I start the server and run try to fire URL `http://localhost:8080/ch1/Serv1` using my browser, I always get `resource not found` error. Why is that so? I feel I have followed all the steps specified in the book well?

Comment: If that web.xml is exactly the one you have on the server then it is malformed xml because it laks the closing tag </web-app> at the end and thus the web app will not be deployed.

Comment: oh sorry, I copied it wrong here, but it has the closing tag.

Comment: do you get any errors when starting tomcat? if yes please add it to your question.

Comment: no, tomcat starts normally.

Comment: do you use any package for your Ch1servlet.java class?

Comment: Just tested your setup, it works just file.

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva if that was the case he would get `HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class Ch1servlet` and not `resource not found`

Comment: @A4L,  in HTTP 404 return code actually means 'resource not found', and applies to any entity for which a request was made but not satisfied. So it works equally-well for pages, subsections of pages, and any item that exists on the page which has a specific request to be rendered. so it will not return 500 return code.

Comment: I think it will, in the case of missing package, return `500`, the server tries to instantiate the class using the name specifyed in web.xml, but there is no such class in the classpath, so a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` occurs -> an internal server error and thus `500`

Comment: @A4L, that is also possible, I did not try this example code...Hey where is this guy **neerajDorle**..? no clue from him....whether it works or not :)

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva I did :)

Answer (score 0):

You should put servlet classes in a java package. Whether packageless servlets works depend on the specific combination of an older Tomcat and JVM version. Here I can see you are using a fairly new Tomcat version and also if you see this example in a book/tutorial, then it is surely outdated.

```js
package com.example;

// ...

public class Ch1Servlet extends HttpServlet {
  // ...
}
```

And your web.xml should be like this:

```html
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns: xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi: schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Chapter1 Servlet
      </servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.example.Ch1Servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Chapter1 Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/Serv1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

have a try and see. I believe your problem is with the package.